# Remove all non-matching characters in PHP string?

Tags: php, regex

I've got text from which I want to remove all characters that ARE NOT the following.

desired_characters =

```
0123456789!&',-./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n
```

The last is a \n (newline) that I do want to keep.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To match all characters except the listed ones, use an [inverted character set `[^…]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
$chars = "0123456789!&',-./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
$pattern = "/[^".preg_quote($chars, "/")."]/";
```

Here [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) is used to escape certain special characters so that they are interpreted as literal characters.

You could also use character ranges to express the listed characters:

```
$pattern = "/[^0-9!&',-.\\/a-z\n]/";
```

In this case it doesn’t matter if the literal `-` in `,-.` is escaped or not. Because `,-.` is interpreted as character range from `,` (0x2C) to `.` (0x2E) that already contains the `-` (0x2D) in between.

Then you can remove those characters that are matched with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'This is anexample $tring! :)';
$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9!&\',\-.\/a-z\n]/', '', $string);

echo $string; // hisisanexampletring!
```

^ This is case sensitive, hence the capital T is removed from the string. To allow capital letters as well, `$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9!&\',\-.\/A-Za-z\n]/', '', $string)`

Comment: The dash in a character class needs to be the first or last character, or be escaped. Else it will indicate a range.

Comment: @kemp - don't know why I missed that! Have edited, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @kemp: That’s not quite right. There are several other cases in which escaping the range indicator is not necessary as it’s not part of a character range: `[-]` (only `-`), `[a-b-c]` (`a`–`b`, `-`, `c`), or `[\d-.]` (`\d`, `-`, `.`).